# "No such module" error appearing in some files

Tags: ios, frameworks, applozic

I have imported the following framework like so:

***import Applozic***

The framework does exist and it works in some files with no error, however in this one file is displaying the error.

I have tried reimporting the framework, doing a clean and build, but just can't seem to solve it. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you check if the target membership of framework and this one file are same?

Comment: yes they both have the same target membership

Comment: Please share the project or any details at support@applozic.com, we will look into it.